# Excel 2016 Power Query fails to load to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016

I utilize Power Query with most of my spreadsheet due to analyzing a large **Excel** data files. This is the first time that I have had an ill-defined error in loading a Power Query connection to the spreadsheet.

Excel Error - "Download did not complete:

[image: Excel Error - "Download did not complete."]

From what I can see, all the "connection only" queries are updating, and the Query updates just fine in the Query editor. There is no error in the data source as another spreadsheet with a Query from the same source loads just fine. I have turned off background refresh, sidestepped the VBA "Refresh Query" and tried a manual refresh, and turned on "Enable tracing" under Query Options. I even went directly into the connection to "Load to..." and selected "Workbook" with no luck. Every time it returns the same vague error. My team member is also having similar issues with the same report on her computer.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you get a more detailed error message if you hover over the query name? (In the preview pop-up).

Comment: Also, is the query being loaded to a worksheet or a data model? Are any of the source files open when you attempt the data load?

Comment: There is no detailed message when I hover over. The query is being loaded to the worksheet and the file was not open.

Comment: Are the source files in a shared location?

Comment: Yes, I have posted how I resolved the issue below. Thank you!

Comment: Hovering over the query name may provide a more detailed error message.  In my case it was because I had enabled Protection on the sheet, which was preventing a refresh.  I'm glad I found this question.

Answer (score 1):

Check that nothing changed in the folder or folder structure your queries are using for source.

I had a similar problem with a big file with multiple queries. Nothing loaded anymore, even though in query editor everything was perfect.
Turns out that someone has created a new folder and added a file that didn't match the rest of the files in the source folder. All the queries that had something to do with the query reading from that folder stopped working.

Everything went back to normal once that extra folder/file were moved somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue has been resolved. I duplicated the Query and loaded to the Worksheet again while deleting the previous sheet. It was not ideal considering all my other objects were referencing the old sheet. For some reason, the duplicated sheet loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem will be with the initial code i.e. the columns you are importing have changed names slightly.

To fix this, reimport it in a new sheet and then copy and paste the first three lines of the import into the original!

Pleasae upvote if this helps :)